# Story [novel, novella?] that featured faster-than-light or hyperdrive gained from observing distant drive use, also had a sentient star

Tags: story-identification, ftl-drive, space-exploration, sentience, time-dilation

I have little recollection when I read this, but it started with people observing indications of some special engine use many lightyears away, and it led them to 'reverse-engineer' the traces to create their own drive.  Had the usual tropes of international crew-selection for first-voyage.

Somewhere in the travel, they encounter a sentient star or quasar.

When they get back hundreds/thousands of years later, they arrive to an uncaring Earth that no longer pursues space-travel.

Comment: Correction: not a star, but a sentient collective of energy in the accretion disk of a black hole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is [Starfarers](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/Starfarers.html?id=qQe83hks6VkC), by Poul Anderson.

I might have to get this off the shelf and read it again tonight.